# Rotating UIViews when screen rotates out of sync

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I am having issues getting UIViews to rotate correctly when the screen rotates. I am reseting the frames of various elements in viewWillLayoutSubviews:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {

    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    //This a transparent black overlay
    cutterView.frame = view.frame
    scrollView.center = view.center

    label.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: cutterView.frame.size.width/2 - label.frame.size.width/2, y: 10)
    okButton.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: cutterView.frame.size.width - okButton.frame.size.width - 12, y: 5)
    backButton.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 10, y: -7)

}
```

The UIScrollView's clipToBounds is set to false. I have content inside that is taller than the screen when orientated landscape. I have a black transparent UIView (cutterView) that overlays the whole view. The rotation works however as the UIScrollView's content is quite tall the top and bottom parts of it are not covered by the overlay until the overlay catches up and rotates to cover the entire view. Is there any workaround to fix this? Could I delay the rotation of the scrollview slightly maybe? Any pointers would be really appreciated. thanks!

Comment: `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is not the right place to coordinate animation with rotation.

Comment: Where is the best place to do it? Is it okay to register a notification for UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification and do it there?

Comment: Implement `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` and use the transition coordinator. That's what it's for, so you can coordinate with the transition.

Comment: @matt thanks mate. Just looked into that and got it working.

Comment: Cool! I'll turn my comments into an answer so that we can complete the story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is not the right place to coordinate animation with rotation. Instead, implement `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` and use the transition coordinator that it gives you. That's what it's for, so you can *coordinate* your animation with the *transition*.